# Deviation when light passed through optical centre

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction

I recently get to know that when light pass through optical centre then it shows a very very slight deviation but why? Why doesnt it pass through optical centre extremely straight?
And can i conclude this that when an light is travelling in direction of optical centre then it is actually travelling along  the normal as in both cases light passes almost undeviated?...
I am really confused ...a help from you will be greatly appreciated..

Comment: Why does a ray passing through optical centre remain undeviated? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/214804/37364

Comment: @mmesser314 in my question i am asking why doesnt it go strainght but in the link u provided tge question is about why doesnt it deviate..

Comment: Are you concluding this from a physical test, or from a geometric calculation?

Comment: @probably_someone i have been taught this in my school

Comment: And it wasn't explained to you how or why this was? Because, as other commenters have pointed out, a ray shouldn't deviate when passing through the optical center.

Comment: @probably_someone but it deviates

Comment: Have you confirmed this for yourself? Or are you just that confident in what you've been taught?

Comment: By deviation, so you mean a change in direction or a parallel displacement? Either way, you should provide a good deal more context for this question.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty  as in this case , there are only 2 mediums(say air and glass lens) so you can consider the meaning of "deviation" to be "parallel displacement"

Comment: Why do you find this that surprising? The same thing happens in a slab of glass with straight parallel surfaces.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty  in a glass slab when   light is along normal (normal incidence) then it doesnt show any lateral displacement but in this case it show a slight lateral displacement

Answer (score 1):

This is simply because real lenses have nonzero thickness, and we must one of several methods for dealing with them, such as those presented on the [Hyperphysics Website](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/geoopt/thklencon.html). But this answer is really a slight generalization of Emilio Pisanty's comment:

> Why do you find this that surprising? The same thing happens in a slab of glass with straight parallel surfaces.

For a nonzero thickness, rotationally symmetric imaging system, the system can be modelled by two *principal planes*.

Principal planes work as follows: you can calculate the paraxial behavior of any ray using them by the following recipe:

1. Ray entering system propagates to the nearest principal plane. In the diagram below, for a ray propagating from left to right, it would meet plane $P_1$ first;
2. The ray then  "teleports" to the other principal plane $P_2$ and begins at the transverse same position relative to the optical axis  as it met the plane $P_1$;
3. The deviation of the ray is calculated as though a thin lens of the same focal length as the whole system's focal length were present at plane $P_2$.

For light propagating from right to left, we have the analogous process on the bottom diagram: propagate to $P_2$, teleport to $P_1$ preserving the transverse position, then the ray is acted on by a thin lens with focal length given by the system's focal length.

The two focal lengths, whether travelling from left to right or right to left, are equal if the refractive indices of the two mediums at either end of the lens are equal. Otherwise, the ratio between the focal lengths is the ratio of the corresponding refractive indices.

[image: Principal Planes]

[image: Principal Planes Backwards]